# Many-To-One with multiple target entities

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

This seems simple but I can't get it right:

There are three entities: `Fruit`, `Vegetable` and `Snack`. Snack has the fields `id`, `time` and `food`. Food is a reference to *either* one fruit *or* one vegetable. So it is basically a many-to-one/one-to-many relationship as one snack will always only hold one food. But there is more than one target entity.

How would I map this in Doctrine2?

A simple solution I would have used before knowing Doctrine2 would be to use two fields: `food_type` and `food_id`. But how can I make a connection from food type to the correct entity? I thought about an array of JoinColumns but can't find a way to connect the correct entity. I also had a look at mapped superclasses because there is a DiscriminatorColumn, but it also seems to be the wrong approach. If I get it right the superclass can't be an entity itself - so I cannot create a food entity.

Any help is appreciated. I'm sure I am missing something simple here.

Comment: have you looked [doctrine's implementation of single table inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a (abstract) mapped superclass called `Food`, which can hold some basic information for `Fruit` and `Vegetable`.

The keyword for your question is `inheritance mapping`, this is the documentation for it: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping

Then you could reference this mapped superclass in your entity relationship.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I got confused by the statement in the doc saying: `A mapped superclass cannot be an entity`.

Comment: @Jenechka: The example in the documentation (see link above, chapter 6.1) actually is a working example.

Comment: Could you please update the link above? It's 404 page now :(

Comment: @stedekay much appreciated